# How to get the call status for outgoing calls?

Tags: android, android-activity, telephonymanager, android-broadcast

I am beginner in android and developing an android application to monitor the network status when the user is on call(for both incoming and outgoing calls)...

i can monitor the network status .for incoming calls by implementing the PhonestateListner class and overriding the onCallStateChanged method, i am  using the constants (CALL_STATE_IDLE,CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK and CALL_STATE_RINGING) defined in the  TelephonyManager class inside the onCallStateChanged method , but these constants are not working properly for outgoing calls...

```
 my question is
```

1. How to monitor the call status(RINGING,OFF_HOOK, IDLE ) when there is  an outgoing call??
2. Is there any API  in android to monitor the call status for outgoing calls??? if yes, then please specify...

please help me to understand this concept... Thanks for your time

Comment: The best way to do this just follow this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/2492925

Answer (score 5):

Below code  help you to get net work status code in onCreate

```
     StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

create an inner class for listening state of phone.

```
class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            System.out.println("call Activity off hook");
            LockScreenActivity.this.finish();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            break;
    }
}
};
```

Set permission in `manifest` file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: **Please**, read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

BroadcastReceiver with action for outgoing call `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` and `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`.

The `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` will be broadcasted when an outgoing call is initiated. The receiving intent will have an extra string variable `Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER` which contains the outgoing number. This requires the permission `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`.

To detect the incoming call, register a BroadcastReceiver for the action `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. This will be broadcasted when there is a change in phone state. The receiving intent will have an extra string variable `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE` which describes the phone state. If this state is `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` then there will be another extra string variable `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER`. This variable contains the incoming phone number. Note that this variable will not be present when the state is not `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`.